# How to parse variable length command line arguments with regex?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a large number of files that each contain a bash command with a variable amount of parameters. I need to replace these with a corresponding API call.

Example bash command in file (Note: number of '-p' arguments vary, some have none):

```
./some_script.sh http://some.server.com -p a=value -p b=value -p c=value
```

Example corresponding API call

```
http://some.server.com/api/some/endpoint?a=value&b=value&c=value
```

My issue is I can't seem to group each parameter, given that the number of parameters is variable.

Basic regex (this will match above example, but only group first parameter):

```
.\/some_script.sh\s([\w\/:\.]*)(\s-\w\s[\w=]*)
```

And I tried:

```
.\/some_script.sh\s([\w\/:\.]*)(\s-\w\s[\w=]*)*
```

However, this seems to only group the last parameter.
(tested with regex101)

Ideally, I would like this regex to be able to group an indefinite number of arguments in these files so that I can easily rebuild the command as an API call.

If more detail is required please let me know, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, maybe we could find another approach, and step by step collect our desired data from our inputs. We would then likely start with an expression similar to:

```
.+\.sh.+?(https?:\/\/[^\s]*)|\s+-[a-z]+\s+([\w=]+)
```

which has our link in here:

```
(https?:\/\/[^\s]*)
```

and our variables in:

```
([\w=]+)
```

altered with a logical OR.

We can also modify and add other boundaries or reduce our boundaries, if that might be desired.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/GCgHaZ/1/)

#### Test

This snippet just shows that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /.+\.sh.+?(https?:\/\/[^\s]*)|\s+-[a-z]+\s+([\w=]+)/gm;
const str = `./some_script.sh http://some.server.com -p a=value -p b=value -p c=value
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, Emma, for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the \G anchor

```
/(?|\.\/some_script\.sh\s([\w\/:.]*)|(?!^)\G())\s-(\w)\s([\w=]*)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/0151qC/1

Expanded

```
 (?|                           # Branch reset
      \. /some_script \. sh         # First, find the script name
      \s 
      ( [\w/:.]* )                  # (1), url

   |                              # or,
      (?! ^ )
      \G                            # Start where last left off
      ( )                           # (1), blank url

 )

 \s - 
 ( \w )                        # (2), - 'p'
 \s 
 ( [\w=]* )                    # (3), 'a=value'
```